# Pivot Field Show All Except Blank

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need to update a pivot filter after refresh to select all filter options except `blank`.
Other answers here make use of `.ShowAllItems` method which will not work for me since that will also show items with no data (pivot option under **Display**).

I tried to use another solution I found on another question, `.PivotItems("(All)").Visible = True` and then remove blank but that does not do anything.

**How can I modify the Pivot Field `Activity Name` to check every item except blank?**

```
Sub PivotRefresh()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "OC" Or ws.Name = "P2" Then
            For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables
                On Error Resume Next
                    pvt.PivotFields("Exclude").PivotItems("Yes").Visible = False
                    pvt.PivotFields("Activity Name").PivotItems("(All)").Visible = True
                    pvt.PivotFields("Activity Name").PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next pvt
        End If
        ws.Range("A:W").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I have to do this, I just use something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
With pvt
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```