# Excel 2016 - VBA - Pivot Table - exclude from copying a row if it contains "(blank)"

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

NOTE: if you are personally unclear on something in this post, constructive route is to ask with specifics of what do you need clarification on.

I have following code, which does what I need - it works with the only pivot table on active worksheet. These pivot tables always have only two columns. Selection excludes header/footer, selects only data. Copies 1st column, pastes it to the right of the 2nd column.   Expands selection to include pasted data and second column - copies that.

Issue: how to exclude from copying a row if it contains "(blank)"

```
Sub PivotPrep4POST()
'
' PivotPrep4POST Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim ws As Worksheet
'selects Row range of pivot
pt.RowRange.Select
'trims two last rows off selection
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 2, Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Select
'shifts selection one row down, resulting in selection minus top and bottom row
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 1).Select
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

Selection.Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Alex: your note at the start has nothing to do with your question. Constructive StackOverflow responders already know how to use the comments to ask constructive follow-up questions. The tone of that note feels a little insulting, and I'd say that having it there adds nothing to your question other than the chance of a down vote.

Comment: NOTE is based on experience, rather than theory, and is not meant to teach how to use comments, rather help some see - not understanding the post does not mean post is not clear, but rather it may be not clear to them, and to further ask for specifics of what they need clarification on, rather than posting declarative "it's not clear".  NOTE is further not intended for constructive respondents or collecting opinions, which add nothing to addressing the question. @jeffreyweir

Comment: We're all volunteers here. If something isn't clear to a volunteer who is taking the time to read your question, then it is *perfectly valid* for them to add a comment along the lines of "Your question/intent is unclear". There is no need for them to add "to me" at the end of that...we know they aren't speaking for the entire SO community. If you've experienced people complaining that you question was unclear, then it's possible it simply wasn't as clear as you thought it was. That's not some fault of them...that's just an opportunity for you to provide more information. To a volunteer.

Comment: Here's what you missed: NOTE is based on experience, rather than theory, calls to ask for specifics of what they need clarification on, rather than posting declarative "it's not clear".  See the difference. Again, NOTE is not intended for constructive respondents or _collecting opinions, which add nothing to addressing the question._ @jeffreyweir

Comment: What "experience"? What "theory"?

Comment: If you can only follow one-liners, here's one - move along @jeffreyweir

Comment: Wow. Your theory and experience match your wit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a bit of code that resizes selection one row short, if it contains "blank" - and this works:

```
Sub PivotPrep4POST2()
'
' PivotPrep4POST Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim ws As Worksheet

'selects Row range of pivot
pt.RowRange.Select
'trims two last rows off selection
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 2, Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Select
'shifts selection one row down, resulting in selection minus top and bottom row
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 1).Select
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select


'Added this
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Selection

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "blank") > 0 Then
    Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Select
    End If
Next cel
'end of addition

Selection.Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying row by row, I suggest it will be much easier and more efficient to filter out blanks, and copy the whole lot in one go to where you need it. Or if you want to rearrange the order of the columns, then copy it column by column.

To see code on filtering out blanks, see [Pivot Field Show All Except Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268064/pivot-field-show-all-except-blank/51270404#51270404)

Jon Peltier has a great post on referencing PivotTable Ranges at https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Adding your code to mine after Dim ws As Worksheet (below code from you on your link) did not make a difference @jeffreyweir : On Error Resume Next
With pt
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With

Answer (score 0):

I threw this together real quick. If you want to check more than one column, you would need to modify, but this should get you started.

```
Sub PivotPrep4POST()
'
' PivotPrep4POST Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim ws As Worksheet
'selects Row range of pivot
pt.RowRange.Select
'trims two last rows off selection
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 2, Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Select
'shifts selection one row down, resulting in selection minus top and bottom row
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 1).Select
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select


'New Code (7/11/2018)
Dim rCell As Range, newRng As Range, tRng As Range

Set tRng = Selection

For Each rCell In tRng.Columns(1).Cells
    If rCell.Value2 <> "(blank)" Then
        If newRng Is Nothing Then
            Set newRng = Intersect(rCell.EntireRow, tRng)
        Else
            Set newRng = Union(newRng, Intersect(rCell.EntireRow, tRng))
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
newRng.Select
'End new code


Selection.Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Almost there, but before copying, code ends up with multiple selections, as it excludes only the cell with "blank" rather than excluding that entire row. Gives "Run-Time error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections."  You could probably knock that issue out in a minute, with your awesome skills?  @PGCodeRider

Comment: @Alex I updated it based on only looking at the first column of your selection. It would be easier if you posted a screenshot or a better example of what you're doing. If that works, please mark off as accepted. thanks.

Comment: Updated 'New Code (7/11/2018)' does not exclude (blank) from selection.  I have already solved my own question a day before and working code is posted here.  Thank you for trying to help! @PGCodeRider